# Произошло исключение. Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, массивы, segmentation-fault

При написании кода в си столкнулся с ошибкой "Произошло исключение.
Segmentation fault" на строчке `m3[i][j] += m1[n][k] * m2[k][l];`. Сначала думал это из-за того что массив m3 не инициализировал, но я попытался инициализировать его нулями, но ошибка не пропала.
Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mul_square_matrix(int  **m1,   int **m2, int **m3,  int n, int m, int l)
{
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
    {
        m3[i][j] = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < m; k++)
        m3[i][j] += m1[n][k] * m2[k][l];
    }
for (int i = 0; i <n; i++)
{
    for (int j; j< l; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", m3[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}


int main()
{
    printf("Input n: ");
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Input m: ");
    int m;
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Input l: ");
    int l;
    scanf("%d", &l);   
    int m1[n][m], m2[m][l], m3[n][l];
    int **p_m1, **p_m2, **p_m3;
    p_m1 = calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
  p_m1[i] = calloc(m, sizeof(int));
}
    printf("Input matrix m1: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("Input [%d][%d] element of matrix m1:", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &m1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    p_m2 = calloc(m, sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) 
{
  p_m2[i] = calloc(l, sizeof(int));
}
    printf("Input matrix m2: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            printf("Input [%d][%d] element of matrix m2:", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &m1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    p_m3 = calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
  p_m3[i] = calloc(l, sizeof(int));
}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            m3[i][j] = 0;   
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    mul_square_matrix(p_m1, p_m2, p_m3, n, m, l);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Столько индексирования и ни единой проверки за выход за пределы массива. В первой же строчке `m1[n]` выйдет. А еще никогда больше не делайте так `int m1[n][m], m2[m][l], m3[n][l];`, собственно для С++ этот код невалиден.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что умножать матрицы нужно правильно:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
{
    m3[i][j] = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < m; k++)
    m3[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
}
```

Вы мало того что множили неверно, так еще и элементы за пределами матрицы...

Answer (score 0):

Уже сам решил проблему. Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void mul_square_matrix(int  **m1,   int **m2,   int **m3, int n,int  m, int l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            m3[i][j] = 0;
            for (int v = 0; v < m; v++)
            {
                m3[i][j] += m1[i][v] * m2[v][j];
            }

        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t" , m3[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
int main()
{
    int n, m, l;
    int **m1;
    int **m2;
    int **m3;
    printf("Input n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Input m: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Input l: ");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    m1 =(int **)calloc(n, sizeof(int*)); // создаю одномерный массив указателей размером n
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        m1[i] = (int *)calloc(m, sizeof(int));// в каждую ячейку одномерного массива помещаю массив указателей размером m
    m2 = (int **)calloc(m, sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0;i < m; i++)
        m2[i] = (int*)calloc(l, sizeof(int));
    m3 =(int **)calloc(n, sizeof(int*)); // создаю одномерный массив указателей размером n
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        m3[i] = (int *)calloc(l, sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            m1[i][j]= rand()%200 - 100;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            m2[i][j] = rand()%200 - 100;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            m3[i][j] = 0;   
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Generated matrix of m1: \n");
    printf("-----------------------\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d \t", m1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("-----------------------\n");
    printf("Generated matrix of m2: \n");
    printf("-----------------------\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
             printf("%d \t", m2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Result (m3) :\n");
    printf("-----------------------\n");
    mul_square_matrix(m1,m2,m3, n,m,l);
    printf("-----------------------\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n;i++)
        free(m1[i]);
    free(m1);
    for(int i = 0; i < m;i++)
        free(m2[i]);
    free(m2);
    for(int i = 0; i < n;i++)
        free(m3[i]);
    free(m3);    
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```